# In Javascript how to retrive button color from a page using 'id'

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

<button id:"foo2"; style="border: 1px solid black; color: rgb(0, 0, 0); background-image: none; background-color: rgb(255, 127, 14);">testbutton</button>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("a[href$='.org']").css("background-color", "yellow");});

</script>
</head>
<body>

<a href="http://www.wikipedia.org">wikipedia.org</a>

</body>
</html>
```

In the above code if i use the command:

```
$("a[href$='.org']").css("background-color")
```

I get

"rgb(255, 255, 0)"

Now how do i get the color of the button 'testbutton' using the id 'foo2'

```
$('foo2').css("background-color") -> does not work
```

Comment: Your jQuery selectors are wrong. `$("foo2")` selects `foo2` elements (tags) which don't exist. Also remember to store the value into a variable. One last thing, attributes are declared inline with `attr=val`, so id is `id="someid"`, and remove semicolon.

Comment: Check out the jQuery docs for see more about how to use selectors. The string you're passing to `$()` is a selector, similar to CSS Selectors

Comment: can you help me with the command to get the color for the button? I am really new to jQuery

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#foo2").css("background-color")
```

you need # prefix to specify that you query the id

and `id:"foo2"` is wrong sintax -> `id="foo2"`

Answer (score -2):

This is how to get elements background-color in JQuery

```
<a id="mylink" href="http://www.wikipedia.org">wikipedia.org</a>

var linkBgColor = $('#mylink').css("background-color");
```